# mobile network friendly host

Tags: iphone, networking, hosting

i am developing an app for iphone, it is a client side application. and i found the 3g network is very slow, should I change the server host to a mobile network friendly host?

any suggestions?

Comment: Your question is confusing.  What does a client-side iPhone application have to do with where you host a server?

Answer (score 1):

Mobile networks are typically high-latency networks, and if you (or your users) are in a bad area, then yeah the network could just suck.

However, its not clear what exactly a "mobile network friendly host" is - I doubt such a thing exists. A bad connection on the client side is just that - you aren't going to be able to overcome that with a server-side change.